# How to call an action method upon selection from the <select> dropdwon in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I created a dropdown using the `<select>` HTML element. Now I want to call an action after user makes a selection from the list.

```
<select name="ddAircraft" id="ddAircraft" class="form-control form-select-sm form-select"  
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ddaircraft,"id","name"))">
</select>
```

I would also like to know if user enter a value in a input box. Then I want to run a Javascript method. How I can do that?

I tried to do `onClick` but I am getting usual error.

Comment: You need to use the on change event rather than on click, since your look for changes rather than clicks   What's the usual error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you could show the details of your error,

I Tried with the codes below:

```
@{
    var sel = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
        new SelectListItem(){Text="1",Value="1" },
        new SelectListItem(){Text="2",Value="2" },
        new SelectListItem(){Text="3",Value="3" }
    };
}
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#selectlist').change(function () {
            window.location.href = "Privacy";
        })
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#input').change(function () {
            window.location.href = "Privacy";
        })
    });
</script>
<input id="input" value=""></input>

<select id="selectlist" asp-items=sel></select>
```

The result:
[image]

To pass the selected item value ,you could try :

```
<script>
    $(function () {        
        
        $('#selectlist').change(function () {
            window.location.href = "Home/Privacy?sel=" + $(this).val();
        })
    });
</script>
```

The result:
[image]

if you want to make a post request, you could try with ajax as below:

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#selectlist').change(function () {
                var sel = $(this).val();
                var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Home/Test",
                    contentType: "application / json; charset = utf - 8",
                    type: "post",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        sel: sel,
                        input: input                    
                    }),
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {                    
                        console.log(data);                    
                    }
                })
    
            })
        });
    </script>
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works for me but how to get the value of the selected item so I can read that in the action method?

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it

Comment: Thanks Ruikai,  it is working fine and I accepted your solution.   Just on the side note, I am navigating to the Get method not on the post.

Comment: I've updated the codes to make a post request,please check it