# <select> dropdown is not recognizing the property from the ViewModel in view using ASP.Net Core MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on the ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.  In view I have created a dropdown with  tag.
I am trying to bind this  dropdown from the ViewModel by following a tutorial from Microsoft document.  I think I am doing everything alright but missing to get the result.
When I try to bind the  with the property, the property is not recognized.  Please see the code below.

//View :  See the code for select. The SelectedValue and Model.ddAircraft are not recognized.

```
@model IEnumerable<Lsap.Models.PlannedPartInstallationViewModel>
```

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Aircraft</label>
 
    <div class="col-sm-3">             
       <select asp-for="SelectedValue" asp-items="Model.ddAircrafts"></select> 
                
    </div>
  
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Disk #</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number"  class="" name="txtDisk" id="txtDisk" placeholder="">
    </div>

</div>


</form>

 <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiskNumber)
         </th>
         '<th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PartID)
         </th>
        
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiskNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartID)
        </td>
        
      
    </tr>

 }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

//Action Method:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data= _aircraftBu.getAircraft();

        List<SelectListItem> dropdown = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach(var a in data)
        {
            var listItem = new SelectListItem();
            listItem.Text = a.Registration;
            listItem.Value = a.Registration;
            dropdown.Add(listItem);
        }
        dropdown.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "0", Value = "Select Item" });
         var listPPVM = new List<PlannedPartInstallationViewModel>();
        var plannedPartInstallation = new PlannedPartInstallationViewModel()
        {
            ddAircrafts = dropdown,
            DiskNumber = "33342",
            PartID = 12343,
            SelectedValue = "Select Item"
        };
        listPPVM.Add(plannedPartInstallation);          
     
        return View(listPPVM);
}
```

/ViewModel

```
   public class PlannedPartInstallationViewModel
{
    
    public int PartID { get; set; }
    public string DiskNumber { get; set; }

    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ddAircrafts { get; set; }
}
```

}

And this is the link I followed for Select tag helpers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<Lsap.Models.PlannedPartInstallationViewModel>` should be `@model Lsap.Models.PlannedPartInstallationViewModel` because the model you create for the view is not a list/collection

Comment: Please make sure the type of data passed from controller to view is the same with the view needed.

Comment: lordvlad30 you are totally correct.  My intention was to send the list.  I have updated the original code to pass the List object.  It is because after the search I am going to populate the grid with on the same view from same ViewModel.

Comment: @Salma After you send the list, The view can road the data successfully?

Comment: No I have the save issue.  Earlier as per your suggestion when I removed the IEnumerable the <select> was fine but this is not my intention. I need to work with the List object because on the same view I have to populate the MVC Grid.

Comment: @Salma, I provide another method you can use dropdownlist with the list object, I hope it can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to write the dropdownlist into your model, you can just  `Viewbag` to pass the items of dropdownlist. Refer to this simple demo.

```
public class PlannedPartInstallationViewModel
{
    
    public int PartID { get; set; }
    public string DiskNumber { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data= _aircraftBu.getAircraft();

        List<SelectListItem> dropdown = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach(var a in data)
        {
            var listItem = new SelectListItem();
            listItem.Text = a.Registration;
            listItem.Value = a.Registration;
            dropdown.Add(listItem);
        }
        dropdown.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "0", Value = "Select Item" });

         //use viewbag to pass the data of dropdownlist form controller to view
         ViewBag.item= dropdown;  

        //.......      
     
        return View(listPPVM);
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Lsap.Models.PlannedPartInstallationViewModel>

//........
<select asp-for="SelectedValue" asp-items="@ViewBag.item"></select>
//.......
```

**Edit=====================================**

Because you pass the list object, So you can't use `asp-for=Model.property` to bind directly.

```
@model IEnumerable<Lsap.Models.PlannedPartInstallationViewModel>

<select name="SelectedValue" >
           @foreach (var item in @Model )
           {
                    @foreach(var option in item.ddAircrafts)
                    {
                        <option value="@option.Value">@option.Text</option>
                    }
                }
       </select>
```

[image]

Comment: I took this approach, but Microsoft does not recommended using the Viewbag or ViewData to populate the dropdown therefore I was looking to populate the the dropdown from the ViewModel .   See the link where I have created the Dropdown and populating it from ViewBag. I I needed help to invoke an action upton selection from dropdown.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454935/how-to-call-an-action-method-upon-selection-from-the-select-dropdwon-in-asp-ne/72455923?noredirect=1#comment128001860_72455923

Comment: OK, I get your point, because you send list object to the view, So you can't use `asp-for=xx` and `asp-items=xxx` to bind property directly, Please  check the answer i update. It meets your requirements

Comment: By the way if I have to select a value by default. What should I do?

Comment: `<option value="@option.Value"  selected="@(option.Text == "xx" ? "selected" : null)" >@option.Text</option>`

Comment: This is how I have done it.  The VM has a property of SelectedValue so I bind selection to it.   It is working fine but the code is in loop I am thinking I could be repeating something over and over again                                                   
 @foreach(var option in item.ddAircrafts)
                    {
                      
                         <option value="@option.Value"  selected="@(option.Text == item.SelectedValue )" >@option.Text</option>

                    }